# Javascript: declare global variable in a script and use it in another

Tags: javascript, html, sql.js

I've been trying to create a connection to an sqlite3 database with a script (main idea came from a stackoverflow answer) which is as follows. In the file "checkbook.js" I have the connection function and below the fuction that is supposed to use the connection, read the database and fill in some fields in a form:

```
function connect_db(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'checks.db', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function fill_status(){
    var contents = window.db.exec("SELECT rowid,name FROM aux_status");
    values = contents[0].values;
    for (j=0;j<values.length;j++){
        var select = document.getElementById('status')
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        select.appendChild(option);
        option.value = values[0];
        option.innerHTML=values[1];
}
```

}

The "checkbook.js" file is invoked in the "checks.html" file which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checkbook v0.0.1</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='images/logo_ioniatex_bbg.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/general.css'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jscripts/general.js'></script>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script src='bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src="sql.js"></script>
    <script src="checkbook.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<script>var db;connect_db();fill_status();</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open the file (in Firefox) I get the message from firebug

```
TypeError: window.db is undefined
var contents = window.db.exec("SELECT rowid,name FROM aux_status");
```

What do I miss? I tried to declare the db variable with or without `var`, even calling the function "fill_status" with `window.db` but still I get the same answer. I would like to run the `connect_db` function at the begining of the html file and after some code to run another which uses the global `db` variable so as not to call an new connection to database for every data extraction I need.

Comment: Tip: add `console.log('This happened!')` or such to 1) the place where `db` is being created and 2) the place where you're trying to use it. You simply have a **timing** problem.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me 2 days time and a broken keyboard!

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
  db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
};
```

is run as a callback of the onload event. Hence, due to the asynchronous nature of the latter, the initialization of `window.db` is not done when:

```
window.db.exec("SELECT rowid,name FROM aux_status");
```

is executed.

You should call `fill_status` as a callback of the other call